# Pygame not detecting mouse clicks

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.8

```py
#The induvidual squares
class Square():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

#The grid as a whole
class Grid():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.squares = []
        self.objects = []
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def populate(self):
        for i in range(1,self.height + 1):
            for j in range(1,self.width + 1):
                self.squares.append(Square(j,i))

grid = Grid(10,10)
grid.populate()
for i in grid.squares:
      grid.objects.append(pygame.Rect((i.x -1) * 50,(i.y - 1) * 50,50,50))

While True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
            print("HELLO") #Testing to see if it worked
            (x,y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for i in grid.objects:
                if i.x*50 <= (x) < (i.x+1)*50:
                    if i.y*50 <= (y) < (i.y+1)*50:
                        print("hi") #Testing to see if it worked
```

I have been experimenting with creating grids and using them to make games. I was looking at being able to click on a certain square of my grid and that would cause a change in that square.

This is where I was attempting to get it to register whether I had clicked any squares however it has not been registering whether I have clicked at all.
I've looked at other discussions on the topic and none have worked.

Comment: See [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in the pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-images-in-pygame/63561152#63561152)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.x` and `.y` component of the `pygame.Rect` object contain the actual top left position of the rectangle. The multiplication by 50 is wrong:

```py
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
            print("HELLO") #Testing to see if it worked
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for obj_rect in grid.objects:
                if obj_rect.x <= x < obj_rect.x+50:
                    if obj_rect.y <= y < obj_rect.y+50:
                        print("hi") #Testing to see if it worked
```

Anyway I recommend to simplify the code and to use `collidepoint`

```py
x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
for obj_rect in grid.objects:
    if obj_rect.collidepoint((x, y)):
        print("hi") #Testing to see if it worked
```

See also [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in the pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-images-in-pygame/63561152#63561152)

Comment: No joy.
I think the problem is more related to the

 for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :

As im not even getting the "Hello" response to say that i have clicked anything

Comment: @royaljames99 Man, I've test that code. It works fine. Your condition is wrong! Of course you've to respect the indentation and `While` -> `while`. I've edit the answer.

Comment: i've just tested putting "print(event)" after the for event in pygame and it isn't printing anything when i click so i think it may be realted to that

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix which is related to me having another

for event in `pygame.event.get()`

in the same while loop.
This event check was used to detect whether I had tried to exit the window. <s>It seems that pygame has an issue with having two event checks in the same loop, possibly related to them using the same variable name</s>, either way, I moved my check into the same for loop and it now works

```
while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    print(event)
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
        print("HELLO")
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for obj_rect in grid.objects:
            if obj_rect.collidepoint((x, y)):
                print("hi") #Testing to see if it worked
```

Comment: *"It seems that pygame has an issue with having two event checks in the same loop*" - not it has not. That is an expected behavior. `pygame.event.get()` removes the events form the queue. So you can't have 2 event loops, because just on of them will receive the events. Furthermore it was impossible to answer the question, because you did not show the 2nd event loop. Please don't insinuate that there is a bug in pygame and correct the answer.