# Function that returns list of tuples with coordinates (x, y), but if you draw rectangles using these coordinates, they should not intersect

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates

*Almost same question answered here: [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collisions-between-two-rectangular-objects-or-images-in-pygame)
But I have generator of coordinates, not rectangles, so I think this topic have to exist.*

The problem is that the function still returns non-unique coordinates, I think there is a mistake in the formula, but I'm not sure, maybe the error is something else.

```
if x1 + 320 > x > x1 or y1 + 120 > y > y1
```

Function that should return unique coordinates:

```
import random
length = 3
items_coord = []
while len(items_coord) < length:
    same = False
    x = random.randint(213, 752)
    y = random.randint(90, 360)
    if len(items_coord) == 0:
        items_coord.append((x, y))
        continue
    for x1, y1 in items_coord:
        if x1 + 320 > x > x1 or y1 + 120 > y > y1:
            same = True
            break
    if not same:
        items_coord.append((x, y))
```

code to check if they cross each other:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((int(pygame.display.Info().current_w // 1.2), int(pygame.display.Info().current_h // 1.2)))
width = int(pygame.display.Info().current_w)
height = int(pygame.display.Info().current_h)
font = pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 15)
running = True

colors = ['green', 'white', 'yellow', 'blue']
items_coords = get_rand_coord(10)
for i in range(10):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, random.choice(colors), (items_coords[i][0], items_coords[i][1], width // 8, height // 12))
pygame.display.update()
while running:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a runable [mre] — not two disjointed snippets of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just verified if the point (`x`, `y`) is not in the rectangular area. (`x`, `y`) is just the top left point of a rectangle. You won't find an intersection if another corner of the new rectangle intersects the other rectangle, but not the top-left point

You have to check whether the rectangles at positions (`x`, `y`) and (`x1`, `y1`) do not intersect. Create [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and use [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) for the collision test:

```py
rect_width = width // 8
rect_height = height // 12
```

```py
same = False
x = random.randint(213, 752)
y = random.randint(90, 360)
rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, rect_width, rect_height) 

# [...]

for x1, y1 in items_coord:
    if rect.colliderect((x1, y1, rect_width, rect_height))
        same = True
        break
```