# Why does my code only sometimes notice collision?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This game is a space shooter and I'm having a weird problem where my lasers only sometimes hit the enemy, and other times pass right through.

```
for lasers in amtLasers:
    if lasers.y < invaders.y:
        if lasers.x > invaders.x-56 and lasers.x < invaders.x+28:
            amtLasers.pop(amtLasers.index(lasers))
            amtInvaders.pop(amtInvaders.index(invaders))
            score += 20
```

I have classes for the lasers and invaders and amtLasers is a list that stores the onscreen lasers until they get deleted. I don't have it set to destroy the enemy on contact, so I was able to notice that if I continue shooting an enemy, the same enemy will get hit sometimes and not get hit other times. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Here's an edit:
The lasers only hit the most recently spawned enemy, and I think I know why

```
class invader(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = randint(30, 1020)
        self.y = 0
        color = randint(1, 3)
        if color == 1:
            self.col = (225,0,0)
        elif color == 2:
            self.col = (0,225,0)
        elif color == 3:
            self.col = (0,115,255)
        self.vel = randint(1, 2)
```

When a new enemy is spawned, invaders.x and invaders.y track that specific enemy and none of the other ones because this class has multiple enemies onscreen at once. How would I track each enemy separately?

Comment: Not really enough information to respond.  try adding more  info.   you might print your lasers.x and linvaders.x in your loop to see if the values make sense.

Comment: Could it be that your lasers move fast enough to move all the way through an enemy in between updates?

Comment: ok I found out something important. It passes through any enemy that isn't the highest up onscreen. This means that when a new enemy spawns at the top, the lasers will pass through every enemy except that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to test to see if any of the lasers hit any of the enemies. Use 2 nested loops to iterate the enemies and the lasers:

```py
for lasers in amtLasers[:]:
    for invaders in amtInvaders[:]:

        if lasers.y < invaders.y:
            if lasers.x > invaders.x-56 and lasers.x < invaders.x+28:
                amtLasers.pop(amtLasers.index(lasers))
                amtInvaders.pop(amtInvaders.index(invaders))
                score += 20
```

Note that you need to iterate over shallow copies of the list. See [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and [`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) for the collision test:

```py
laser_rect = pygame.Rect(laser.x, laser.y, laser_width, laser_height)
invader_rect = pygame.Rect(invaders.x, invaders.y, invaders_width, invaders_height)

if laser_rect .colliderect(invader_rect):
    amtLasers.pop(amtLasers.index(lasers))
    amtInvaders.pop(amtInvaders.index(invaders))
    score += 20
```

See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907) and [How to detect collisions between two rectangular objects or images in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63561028/how-to-detect-collision-between-two-images-in-pygame/63561152#63561152).